# Define function in matlab without using new function

Tags: function, matlab

I have a matlab file for my codes , I want to define a new function in this file and I don't  want to add new file for this function because this file is my codes that control agents in Webots , and controller file must be single file.
Functions must be define first of my codes in file or last of them or ...?

Comment: Is the file a script or a function?

Comment: see http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html

Comment: this file is a script file

Comment: if I insert my function in first of my script codes , an error happened that said my script codes is not in any function

Comment: That's why I asked, the link provided by @H.Muster can define multiple functions in one file, but not defining function in a script.

Comment: is not any way for define function and scripts in one file?

Comment: No, there is not. Why does your file need to be a script?

Comment: because I have some codes like for loops and etc.. and I need to call some function in them

Comment: Can I make my scripts a new function beside other function and make this script function to run first?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just start your file with a `function yourFunctionName()` statement and you are free to define additional local functions in your file. Please see: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html

Answer (score 3):

You cannot define a function within a script, but you *can* define a local function within a function m-file... So, suppose your script looks like this:

```
blah blah         %// This is your main code

%// Here you want to add another function, for example:
function y = foo(x)
    y = x + 2;
```

If you try to do what is shown above, you'll get the following error:

> `Function definitions are not permitted at the prompt or in scripts.`

However, if you simply change your main script into a function, you'll be able to define local functions:

```
function mainfunc %// Main function name to your choosing
blah blah         %// This is your main code

function y = foo(x)
    y = x + 2;
```

Since your `mainfunc` doesn't accept nor return any arguments, you can run it like an ordinary script. Also note that it is recommended for the main function and the m-file to share the same name.

**EDIT**: Shai mentions in a comment that there is a caveat here though: while scripts have access to the variables in the main workspace, functions have their own scope. Keep that in mind. Nevertheless, you can still manipulate workspace variables with the [`load`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html), [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html), [`evalin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html) and [`assignin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html) commands.

Comment: Another comment- if you encapsulate your script in a function, when you run it, resulting variables created in the script will not be kept at working environment. Moreover, if the script uses variables already defined on the workspace, these will not be available when the function runs.  **A script and a function are using DIFFERENT scopes**.

Comment: @Shai Good point, but this can be sidestepped by using `save` and `load`. A bit cumbersome, but it works.

Comment: While you are at it, it can be sidestepped using `evalin` and `assignin`... fewer disk access...

Comment: I've amended the answer. Your comments are appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

If your function is very small, you can define it as an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)

Comment: No , my function is not very small

Answer (score -2):

I think using eval is  a solution for your case

put your function in a string variable.

```
% script
subfun = 'do something with input parameter param, and assign to output variable'
param = xxx;
output = 0;
eval(subfun);
% Then access the output here
```

Here is one example

```
% Script
subfun = 'output=param^2;output=output^2;'
param = 5;
output = 0;
eval(subfun);
disp(output);
```

Comment: I don't think that this is terribly good advice to someone who is, judging by the question and the comments made, a beginner in Matlab.  `eval` has its place but that place is not in trying to write script files which contain local function definitions. OP would be better following the thrust of @H.Muster's comments.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark If the function needed is very big, and needs multiple lines, even if you use anonymous function you need the help of eval. As far as I know, there is no lambda for matlab. And even inline function is just a wrapper for eval.